# Suppressing fatal error (access denied)

Tags: powershell, wmi

Going round in a circle here...
I'm trying to handle and continue from 'fatal errors' in scripts. I know the `-EA silentlycontinue` doesn't work but keep coming back to using `foreach` to get around it but solutions I find don't work for me for example and this is an example not what I'm trying to do...

The code:

```
get-content serverLists.txt | 
foreach {get-wmiobject -computer $_ -query "Select * from win32_logicaldisk where drivetype=3"} | 
Format-Table SystemName,DeviceID,Size,FreeSpace,VolumeName
```

Dies with:

```
get-wmiobject : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
At line:1 char:40
+ get-content serverLists.txt | foreach {get-wmiobject -computer $_ -query "Select ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WmiObject], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

I want it to just continue, I've tried and investigated try/catch this just gives me the error in a readable format and stops, I've looked at ping/port check solutions but some servers are behind firewalls but certain ports are open etc I just want it to handle the fatal error and just carry on...

BTW this isn't a rights issue, it'll pass through a whole bunch of servers fine then the script will die on one and stop

Answer (score 2):

`try..catch` should do what you want:

```
Get-Content serverLists.txt | % {
  try {
    gwmi -Computer $_ -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType=3"
  } catch {}
} | Format-Table SystemName,DeviceID,Size,FreeSpace,VolumeName
```

or you could change `$ErrorActionPreference`:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
Get-Content serverLists.txt | % {
  gwmi -Computer $_ -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType=3"
} | Format-Table SystemName,DeviceID,Size,FreeSpace,VolumeName
```

Comment: Like I say I've tried try/catch and what I've done so far like yours doesn't give an error but the script just stops and exits at where the error would be.

Comment: It worked just fine when I tested it. If your script terminates from this, something else is going on.

Comment: Which is why I feel like I'm going round in circles, is there a setting in Powershell?

Comment: Here's the output:-
PS P:\Scripts\PShell> Get-Content serverLists.txt | % {
  try {
    gwmi -Computer $_ -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType=3"
  } catch { Write-Warning "Oops: $_"}
} | Format-Table SystemName,DeviceID,Size,FreeSpace,VolumeName


SystemName  DeviceID Size  FreeSpace VolumeName                
----------  -------- ----  --------- ----------                     
Server1   C:  17178783744 5391642624 SYSTEM
Server2   D:  21467947008 19921707008 DATA
WARNING: Oops: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior. What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: $psversiontable.psversion gives me Version 3, This is from running it in ISE. Just tried from a normal Powershell window and it does the same.

Comment: Try identifying which line from the input file causes the error.

Comment: That's not the point, it's a server I have no access to so it fails, the point is this will happen but I need the script to continue, report the error but continue...

Comment: Ahhhhhh!!! It basically works as expected in the foreach format but by unhappy coincidence every time I had my list of servers to run and test the last one had a access denied message so it looks like it always halted at that point in the script not the fact that was the end of the list! Doh!